# TeXlipse install path and file path with spaces

Tags: texlipse

I had the problem not to be able to place the TeXlipse plugin in my preferred repo because the path to it contains spaces. Also contain paths to files spaces. It seems the plugin contains a bug in interpreting the supplied parameters!

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in the TeXlipse plug-in at the moment `\"C:` will be escaped to `"C:` but `texlipse.jar\"` will NOT be escaped to `texlipse.jar"` but `texlipse.jar\` PLUS the `"`-sign, which will end our String. The line below contains some workarounds and will allow you to have spaces in the path pointing to the plugin and in the paths pointing to the files. My file names never contain spaces so I can't say anything about that. You will get many more problems when having spaces in the source file names such as "My Tex Source.tex" instead of "MyTexSource.tex".

```
-reuse-instance -inverse-search "javaw -classpath \"C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\kec\plugins\net.sourceforge.texlipse_1.5.0\texlipse.jar\"; net.sourceforge.texlipse.viewer.util.FileLocationClient -p 55123 -l %l -f \"%f\""
```

The following image shows the setup[image]

Keep in mind that if using this setup the first instance of Sumatra PDF reader must be started through Eclipse to apply the supplied arguments correctly. This must only be done once unless you are using multiple IDEs manipulating the `-inverse-search` parameter.

## Update1

Adding `"%fullfile"` to the `-reuse-instance` parameter solves an issue with Eclipse Luna regarding its response when starting Sumatra for the first time.

```
-reuse-instance "%fullfile" -inverse-search "javaw -classpath \"C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\kec\plugins\net.sourceforge.texlipse_1.5.0\texlipse.jar\"; net.sourceforge.texlipse.viewer.util.FileLocationClient -p 55123 -l %l -f \"%f\""
```

Hints for search options:

Forward search with Sumatra (see image) is reached via CTRL+4 whereas forward search with Pdf4Eclipse is reached via CTRL+ALT+F resp. ALTGR+F, don't expect this shortcut to work with Sumatra, its a feature of Pdf4Eclipse.

Inverse search support option must be changed to `Viewer runs external command` (see image).